# Java return type generic

Tags: java, generics

I'm newbie in using generic in java, i have simple method that i would like to return any type from that, this method return other class `getters` methods, for example i have `channels` class and that have `getChannelId()` method, i want to return that from this method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Channels> T getChannelColumn(ChannelContentModel.channelColumns column) {
    switch (column) {
        case id:
            return (T) channel.getId();
        break;
        case title:
            return (T) channel.getChannelTitle();
            break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

`getId` is int and `getChannelTitle` is string, how can i fix this method to return any type?

in my code `channel` is instance of `Channels` class, Thanks in advance

Comment: Java is statically typed. That makes it impossible to write a method which can return an `int` or a `String` in different situations. It would only work if there was a supertype of `int` and `String`.

Comment: What is a potential caller going to do with the retun value of a  method that sometimes returns an int and sometimes a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Geckstar;

> Java is statically typed

But it is possible to clear your code sample from compile errors.

1. Remove breaks, because there is no need to break after return statement.
2. extend return type from object. T extends Object instead T extends Channel
3. id must be Integer, not int or change to (T)(Integer) channel.getId()

> This is not a good solution, it only fixes compile errors.But this method's usage may cause runtime failures.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Object> T getChannelColumn(ChannelContentModel.channelColumns column) {
    switch (column) {
        case id:
            return (T) channel.getId(); //int must be Integer
        case title:
            return (T) channel.getChannelTitle();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I get `Inconvertible` error for `return (T) channel.getId(); `

Comment: did you check channel.getId() method, it must return Integer not int or cast as (T)(Integer) channel.getId();

Comment: negative point owner, please give the best answer to help newbie. please do not put negative and run away

Comment: oh, really `T extends Object`?

Comment: Still there is no answer to question owner, only trying to dispraise. Did you not see as "not good" parts of text. Yes, this is a bad answer but as I said PLEASE, give the best answer and describe problem to question owner ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create property wrapper which will hold the value in string data format when required it will convert to a specific data type.

```
public class MyProperty {
private String stringVal;

public MyProperty(String stringVal) {
    this.stringVal = stringVal;
}

public Integer getInteger() throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return integerValue.getValue();
}

public String getString() {
    return stringValue.getValue();
}

private PropertyValue<String> stringValue = new PropertyValue<String>() {
    protected String parse(String rep) {
        return rep;
    }
};
private PropertyValue<Integer> integerValue = new PropertyValue<Integer>() {
    protected Integer parse(String rep) throws NumberFormatException {
        return Integer.valueOf(rep);
    }
};

private abstract class PropertyValue<T> {
    private T value;

    protected abstract T parse(String rep) throws Exception;

    public T getValue() throws IllegalArgumentException {
        try {
            value = (stringValue == null) ? null : parse(stringVal);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            value = null;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

}

you can make specialize class or one class having the access method to get the value with specified data type

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public  MyProperty getChannelColumn(ChannelContentModel.channelColumns column) {
        switch (column) {
            case id:
                return new MyProperty(channel.getId());//
            break;
            case title:
                return new MyProperty(channel.getChannelTitle());
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: All value will be wrapped in PropertyValue.So you will return the PropertyValue and client class will get the required value like int,string

Comment: could you take an example to know how can i do that?